# I cen't save vairrabre to text file

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function that generates a report with calculations. I want to save the report as a text file.

This is my code:

```
def pom(DF):
    father = len(DF[(DF.kro == 10)])
    mother = len(DF[(DF.krm == 10)])
    allAnimals = len(DF)
    x = print(f'''Numbers of animals {allAnimals}\n
    Numbers of animals where father is wbp - {father}\n
    Numbers of animals where mother is wbp - {mother}''')
    return x

test = pom(DF)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(test)
```

When I use with open I get error:`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None`
The function should return x print but when I call the test variable nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your pom() function, you made x = print()

This means that your x will contain the return value of the print function => None.

Just remove the print() and make x equal to the string between quotes.

If you want to print the result just add a new instruction:

```
print(x)
```